multiselect chips with custom label chips
<p-multiSelect
      [options]="employees"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployees[question.id]"
      [optionValue]="'nip'"
      [optionLabel]="'label'"
      display="chip"
      [placeholder]="'Select Employees'"
      [filter]="true"
      [emptyFilterMessage]="'No options found'"
      [style]="{ width: '20vw' }"
    >
    </p-multiSelect>

this is my multiselect primeng with data like below
this.employees = this.questions.output_schema.employee.map(
  (employee: Employee) => ({
    nip: employee.nip,
    name: employee.name,
    label: `${employee.nip} - ${employee.name}`, // this is custom label
  })
);

in the multiselect dropdown, the label shows as 'NIP - NAME'
but in the chips, i want to only show the name
is there any way i could achieve this?

Instead of modifying the actual data, just create a template, which will show the extra text.
Primeng multiselect - template
Primeng multiselect - template docs
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
    <p-multiSelect
        [options]="countries"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries"
        placeholder="Select a Country"
        optionLabel="name"
    >
        <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
        {{item.name}} - {{item.code}}
        </ng-template>
    </p-multiSelect>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

i tried this too, but it doesnt work. maybe because i use 'display : chip' (?)

@MAY please replicate the issue in the stackblitz and share back, require the issue to happen in stackblitz for debugging
